# Drupal node_save no longer returns $nid, so how do I get it?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I have code like this:

```
... setup $issue object ...
$node = node_save($issue);

print_r($node);
```

The node is created successfully, and everything works fine...but nothing it returned from save_node().  Older docs indicate that it returns $nid.  Several discussions and tickets indicate that in recent Drupal versions the node object is returned, but I get nothing back (and $node->nid is empty).

So, how do I find out the nid of the newly created node?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

OK, finally figured this one out (and boy do I feel silly).

node_save now operates on the existing node object (already defined in $issue in my case), and simply adds the nid field (among others) to the existing object.  Nothing is returned, but I can access the nid with $issue->nid after node_save has run.

Comment: Always great to see someone following up to help save others some frustration. Thank you a year later!

Answer (score 0):

Thank You! Very good to know. Thank You for answering your own question and sharing so others (like myself) can learn! Good solution! Thanks for contributing

2 tips:

//use drupal_set_message() to inform the user that the node was successfully saved

//try using node_submit() before saving to catch error that might exist

```
if ($_newnode = node_submit($_newnode)) {
    node_save($_newnode);
    drupal_set_message(t("Node ".$_newnode->title." added correctly"));
    $return = $_newnode->uid;
} else {
    $return = 0;
    drupal_set_message(t("Node ".$_newnode->title." added incorrectly"), "error");
}

return $return;
```